# Angular/Typescript: Rename individual enum values in a dropdown menu

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

Say I have an enum which is just

```
export enum TestEnum {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C',
}
```

and in my components.ts method you can find this:

```
optionsTestEnum: SelectItem[];

  initDropdownOptionsEnum() {

    this.optionsTestEnum = Object.keys(TestEnum).map(v => {
      return { label: v, value: v };
    });
  }
```

SelectedItem takes the enum values from a java backend.

TestEnum.java:

```
public enum TestEnum {
  A, B, C
}
```

and my component.html is something like this:

```
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
          <si-newton-form-group [label]="'testFlag' | translate" ccFormGroup>
            <p-dropdown [options]="optionsTestEnum" formControlName="testFlag" 
                        [ccDisabled]="readOnly" ccNewton>
            </p-dropdown>
            <cc-input-validationmessage [form]="testForm" controlName="testFlag">
            </cc-input-validationmessage>
          </si-newton-form-group>
        </div>
```

I would like to do an if, else statement where I can choose the values from the testenum (A,B,C) and rename these variables individually using

```
this.translate.instant(''),
```

If I write something like this:

```
    this.optionsTestEnum = Object.keys(TestEnum).map(v => {
      return { label: this.translate.instant('testEnum.test1'),, value: v };
    });
  }
```

the dropdown menu in my front-end only shows me that all three values from the enum (A,B,C) have now the same name.

The translation:

```
this.translate.instant(''),
```

uses an json file in my case en.json.

```
    "testEnum": {
        "test1": "Test 1",
        "test2": "Test 2",
        "test3": "Test 3",
```

The values from my enum instead should have the names from the json file. A should be renamed to Test 1, B should be renamed to Test 2 and C should be renamed Test 3. So how can I write an if condition in component.ts that renamed my variables correctly?

Could anybody help me?

Comment: I don't really see what the problem is

Comment: The values from my enum (A,B,C) should get renamed individually by using an if condition in component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
this.optionsTestEnum = Object.keys(TestEnum).map(v => {
      return { label: this.translate.instant('testEnum.test1'), value: v };
    });
```

You are translating each of your `v`s to the string 'testEnum.test1', so you always get "Test 1".

What you want to do is something like:

```
    this.optionsTestEnum = Object.keys(TestEnum).map(v => {
      return { label: this.translate.instant('testEnum.' + v), value: v };
    });
```

This way you will translate the strings 'testEnum.A', 'testEnum.B' and 'testEnum.C'. Now you just have to put the translation for A,B,C in your translate file like:

```
 "testEnum": {
    "A": "Test 1",
    "B": "Test 2",
    "C": "Test 3"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to rename your tranlations keys to reflect the Enum Keys :

```
"testEnum": {
    "testA": "Test 1",
    "testB": "Test 2",
    "testC": "Test 3",
```

and then

```
this.optionsTestEnum = Object.keys(TestEnum).map(k => {
      return { label: this.translate.instant(`testEnum.test${k}`),, value: k };
    });
  }
```